# django-storages + factoryboy: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, django, factory-boy, python-django-storages

I'm working on a Django project that is going to use `AWS S3` to serve `static`/`media` files. 
To this end I've installed both boto3 and django-storages, using [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html) post as an example.

Our project also uses `FactoryBoy` to help with our tests. However, the new setup causes al factories with `FileFields` or `ImageFields` to fail with the following error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

The model is as follows:

```
class AcademySettings(models.Model):
    (...)
    logo = models.ImageField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        storage=PublicMediaStorage(),
    )
```

Its using the `PublicMediaStorage()` object, inspired by the post linked above and which is defined as follows:

```
class PublicMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    """ Public media """

    location = settings.AWS_PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION
    file_overwrite = False
```

The model has the following factory:

```
class AcademySettingsFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'core.AcademySettings'

    (...)
    logo = factory.django.ImageField(color='red')
```

The `PublicMediaStorage` class uses the `AWS_PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION` variable, which is defined in the settings:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME: str = 'project-name-hidden'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME: str = 'project-name-hidden'
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN: str = '{}.s3.amazonaws.com'.format(
        AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    )
AWS_LOCATION: str = 'backend'
AWS_PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION: str = AWS_LOCATION + '/public'
```

And finally, this test itself - for the purposes of this post a simple init will suffice:

```
class TestAcademySettingsModel(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.academy_settings = AcademySettingsFactory()

    def test_init(self) -> None:
        self.assertTrue(self.academy_settings)
```

---

It seems that the values generated by `factory.django.ImageField()` are incompatible with the correct `django-storages` setup, but I'm not really sure on how to solve this.

Our project has a very high test-coverage and uses `FactoryBoy` in virtually all of them, so abandoning `FactoryBoy` is not really an option.

I was wondering if anyone else has created a project using both `FactoryBoy` and `django-storages` and if they also ran into these problems (and if so, how did you manage to solve them?)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT**

As requested I've included the stacktrace as requested

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/src/core/tests/testmodels.py", line 102, in setUp
    self.academy_settings = c_factories.AcademySettingsFactory()
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 46, in __call__
    return cls.create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 564, in create
    return cls._generate(enums.CREATE_STRATEGY, kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 141, in _generate
    return super(DjangoModelFactory, cls)._generate(strategy, params)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 501, in _generate
    return step.build()
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 279, in build
    kwargs=kwargs,
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/base.py", line 315, in instantiate
    return self.factory._create(model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/factory/django.py", line 185, in _create
    return manager.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1334, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1278, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1278, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1277, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1228, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 288, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 87, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 51, in save
    name = self.get_available_name(name, max_length=max_length)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 620, in get_available_name
    return super(S3Boto3Storage, self).get_available_name(name, max_length)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 75, in get_available_name
    while self.exists(name) or (max_length and len(name) > max_length):
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 520, in exists
    self.connection.meta.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=name)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 276, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 559, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 605, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model, context)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 637, in _emit_api_params
    params=api_params, model=operation_model, context=context)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/home/jasper/PycharmProjects/ewise_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py", line 223, in validate_bucket_name
    if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace leading to the `TypeError`? Without that, it's hard to say where the invalid data type is used!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've included the stack trace as requested.

Comment: The error seems to come from an unexpected type of `self.bucket_name` in `s3boto3.py`, which appears to come from `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`. I see you've redacted it, does its type match what you intended?